# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with message 'Syntax error, unexpected token >,

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, controller, phalcon

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with
>   message 'Syntax error, unexpected token >, near to ' LIMIT :APL0:',
>   when parsing: SELECT [Multiple\Backend\Models\urunler].* FROM
>   [Multiple\Backend\Models\urunler] WHERE urunNo => LIMIT :APL0: (111)'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\BestShop\apps\backend\models\urunler.php:42 Stack
>   trace: #0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->parse() #1
>   [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->execute() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\BestShop\apps\backend\models\urunler.php(42):
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Model::findFirst(Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\BestShop\apps\backend\controllers\UrunController.php(56):
>   Multiple\Backend\Models\urunler->sil(NULL) #4 [internal function]:
>   Multiple\Backend\Controllers\UrunController->silAction('125') #5
>   [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch() #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\BestShop\public\index.php(98):
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle() #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\BestShop\public\index.php(105): Application->main() #8
>   {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\BestShop\apps\backend\models\urunler.php on line 42

**Model**

```
public function delete($id){
    $product = products::findFirst(
            array(
                    "conditions" =>"urunId => $id"
            ));
    $product->delete($id);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function deleteAction(){
   $product = new products();
   $product->delete($this->request->getPost('id'));
}
```

**View**

```
<td>{{ link_to("admin/product/delete/" ~ detay.urunId, 'Delete') }}</td>
```

Comment: where is the error line??

Comment: array("conditions" =>"urunId =" . $id)

Comment: in your code, something else it there...

Answer (score 0):

```
public function delete($id){
    $product = products::findFirst([
                "conditions" =>"urunId = $id"
            ]
    $product->delete($id);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function delete() on boolean in ???

 $product->delete($id);

Comment: If you examine the query result, it will probably be a false. If you read the source code, you will see that false gets returned when no such tuple/model exists.

public function delete($id)
    {
        $product = products::findFirst([
                "conditions" => "urunId = $id"
            ]
        );
        
        if (!$product){
            // do stuff, fx:
            // 1) throw new \Exception('No such model in our db')
            // 2) return false
            // 3) OR however else u wanna handle it
        }
        $product->delete($id);
    }

Comment: Also its a good idea to keep your classes with capital first letter, and in singular, e.g.: Product::findFirst();

Comment: I do not want to delete the record

Comment: Why to model delete function in model, where Phalcon already offers it? You Have syntax error spoted by Niranjan. You should use `'bind'` opt